# C# legacy closes after loading

Tags: c#

​
Hi

I have a C# legacy application (exe file) that automatically closes after loading. No source code available.

It connects to SQL Server using the connection string with an integrated security.

I tested SQL server connection with Sqlcmd on command line, it works well.

How can I troubleshoot this application without the source code?. Has something change on how we connect to SQL Server?

Strangely, it works if I run as administrator (run the exe), but does not connect to the SQL Server data (data is not populating)

Thank you so much.

Kind regards.

David

Answer (score 0):

David,

You could use a tool such as JustDecompile from Telerik or dotPeek from JetBrains to look at the source code.  Not always pretty, but it is probably your best bet.  Hope that helps.

Wade